# jQuery Same function with different classes on mouseenter

Tags: jquery

I'm not quite sure how to call it so my search was limited. Am sorry if duplicate.

So I want to use a function on mouseenter but the divs are different and the child divs are different. I want to create the effect that when someone hovers over a column the text appears. But only the text from that particular div. However the function is the same. So I was wondering if there is a solution to this besides copy pasting the same function and change names.
So far I thought it would look something like this:

```
jQuery(firstColumn).add(secondColumn).on('mouseenter', function() {
    if(that.is(firstColumn){
        jQuery(firstColumnText).addClass('show');
    }else if(that.is(secondColumn)){
        jQuery(secondColumnText).addClass('show');
    }
});
jQuery(firstColumn).add(secondColumn).on('mouseleave', function() {
    if(that.is(firstColumn){
        jQuery(firstColumnText).removeClass('show');
    }else if(that.is(secondColumn)){
        jQuery(secondColumnText).removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

Or if there's something even more neat I'd like to learn that.

Comment: Please post some html code too in order to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery provides mouseover and mouseout listeners, to which you can bind functions to add class or change CSS:

```js
$(".hover-to-show-text").each((index, elt) => {
  $(elt).mouseover(() => {
    $(elt).find(".hidden-text").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(elt).mouseout(() => {
    $(elt).find(".hidden-text").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```css
.hover-to-show-text {
  padding: .3em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover-to-show-text">
  <p>Hover to show text</p>
  <p class="hidden-text">Some text</p>
</div>
<div class="hover-to-show-text">
  <p>Hover to show text</p>
  <p class="hidden-text">Some text</p>
</div>
<div class="hover-to-show-text">
  <p>Hover to show text</p>
  <p class="hidden-text">Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This was indeed what I was looking for. I didn't think of the .each(). Thanks for the enlightment.